# Vb.net : How can i Click 2 buttons at the same time?

Tags: vb.net

i'm just a beginner here, please help me to solve my problem, and actually i didn't have a code yet for this.

i have a 2 flow out panel and have a buttons. the Menu button in the upper side and the Menu button in the bottom side. how can i click them at the same time?

Comment: This isn't physically possible: you only have a single mouse pointer on-screen? Or do you mean you want the `Button_Click` code for each button in quick-succession?

Comment: so it depends on my screen? if it is single mouse pointer screen or multi mouse pointer on screen?

Comment: Windows does not support multiple mouse-pointers, so it isn't possible to click two buttons at the same time on Windows - that's why I'm unsure about what exactly you're asking for.

Comment: There's no such thing as a multi mouse pointer screen.  You can only click one control at a time.  PERIOD!  Please explain what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than how you're trying to achieve it.

Comment: actually i'm creating a table side ordering system for our thesis, and i'm creating an ordering method for 2 person per table. and it's menu is upside down so that the customer can order in their seats. and what if the customer order at the same time. thats why i asked this kind of quesiton hehehe, anyway, thanks for enlightening my mind that this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do that, but there is a way to achieve your problem,
Do something like this,

This is only a suggestion..

```
Private Sub btnMenuUpper_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMenuUpper.Click
 'Code Here
End Sub
```

That's the first button and that will be activate also the second button.

```
Private Sub btnMenuBottom_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMenuBottom.Click
 'Code Here
End Sub
```

And just call the `btnMenuBottom` to `btnMenuUpper`.

```
Private Sub btnMenuUpper_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMenuUpper.Click
 'Code
  btnMenuBottom_Click(sender, e)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Private Sub btn1_click(sender as object, e as EventArgs) handles btn1.click
 btn2.performclick
end sub
```